# How to store Set object in chrome local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

```
var testSet = new Set(); testSet.add(1); testSet.add(2);
chrome.storage.local.set( { 'key': testSet }, function() { chrome.storage.local.get( 'key', function(data){ console.log(data) }); });
```

This outputs

```
Object {key: Object}
key: Object__proto__: 
Object__proto__: Object
```

Why doesn't it show the testSet values in there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve this, is by converting your `Set` into an array by using [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

**E.g.**

```
var testSet = new Set(); testSet.add(1); testSet.add(2);
chrome.storage.local.set({ 'key': [...testSet] });
```

And when you want to retrieve it, you can do it like..

```
chrome.storage.local.get('key', function(data){ 
    var mySet = new Set(data.key);
    console.log(mySet);
})
```

*Edit: Thanks for Xan's comment to notice that `chrome.storage` could set an array directly.*

Comment: Why the JSON conversion?

Comment: Was about to upvote, but yes, serializing using JSON is completely unnecessary.

Comment: The doc says "User data can be stored as objects (the localStorage API stores data in strings)." https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: I'm suggesting storing the array directly. `chrome.storage` internally stores as strings, but accepts `Array`, no need to double-serialize.

Comment: @mik Exactly; `localStorage` API can only store strings. Chrome Storage API is better than that.

Comment: Also, parsing `data` instead of `data.key` is not going to re-create the original set.

Comment: @Xan It'd really accept array? I'll just confirm it once I get back to my PC then.. Thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: It will; I am storing `Set`s in my extension this way, though spread operator is a nifty way to do it.

Comment: @Xan Wow.. I just notice this and it actually works.. Thanks for the insight, it's a new stuff for me..

Comment: Basically, anything JSON-serializable is fair game. I just tested with `{"a": ["b", "c"], "d": {"e": 1}}` and it _just works_. The only downside to storing non-primitives is that you can't do "deep" updates: you have to get/set the whole thing again.

Comment: @Xan I see, it looks like even though Set is type of object, it would not serialize when setting it into a storage coz its not json serializable. The docs actually say the otherwise :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114830/discussion-between-xan-and-choz).

Answer (score -2):

From the chrome API docs:

```
StorageArea.get(string or array of string or object keys, function callback)
```

So it looks like you can only use primitives and objects containing primitives.

Comment: Can you point me where it says that you can can object containing primitives?

Comment: [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-set): _"Primitive values such as numbers will serialize as expected. Values with a typeof "object" and "function" will typically serialize to {}, with the exception of Array (serializes as expected), Date, and Regex (serialize using their String representation)."_

Comment: Also, you can simply test it; JSON-serializable things (objects made up of primitives and arrays) are directly working.

Comment: I initially upvoted this, but now that I re-read it it's nonsense. You quote the signature for _queries_ to the storage, not data to be stored.